# Adding Timecodes in Excel

Tags: excel, duration, timecodes

I have about 140 cells (they are in a vertical column) containing Timecodes in the Format hh:mm:ss:ff. 
There are 24 Frames per second. 
I would like to add them, so I have a total duration of all extracts.
Can anyone tell me how I could do that in Micosoft Excel?
Any help is greatly appreciated, since I am literally clueless...Thanks so much in advance!!

[image]

Comment: What would a duration look like between, say, `00:01:07:07` and `00:01:07:09`. Would it be measured as 2 frames or 1/12 second or what?

Comment: My lists consists of durations already, so it would be 00:00:00:2

Answer (score 1):

You can get the duration in frames by doing some math. First you have to pick out each portion of the timestamp (Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and Frames), then just math that up to get the number of frames since some prior point in time (00:00:00:00). From that you can derive the duration each frame is from it's predecessor and sum the results for the total:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Since I have to do it several times (sometimes only for three cells, sometimes for 40) that is a bit too much of a hustle. But thank you anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way (or maybe it is?), but it works.

1. Separate hh:mm:ss from ff.
2. Sum hh:mm:ss and ff respectively.
3. Add frames to hh:mm:ss.

[image: Excel]

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up just calculating without the frames with a very approximate number, but in a later phase of this project I will probably use this! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code is from my excel complement "TCCalculator". The calculator is free but not the code.
I can put here the link to my Google Drive if the moderator gives me his permission

You must to do three things.

```
1- Create a Button to start the calculation (ButtonTC).
2- Create some VBA functions (I will show it to you)
3- Select a range and click on ButtonTC
```

With this method we can select ranges of different cells. It will make the sum of all.

All you need are these functions:

Private Sub ButtonTC_Click

```
Private Sub ButtonTC_Click()
    Dim framesRef As Double
    ‘framesRef can be 23.98, 24, 25, 29.97…
    'Beware, the decimal point may vary depending on the system configuration
    'The cell that will store the final result must be free of data. We can also get the result with a msgbox
        Cells("1", "A") = f_CalculateRangeTC(framesRef)
End Sub
```

Public Function f_CalculateRangeTC

```
Public Function f_CalculateRangeTC(ByVal framesRef As Double) As String
Dim obj_Cell As Range
Dim sumaTotalFrames As Double
        sumaTotalFrames = 0
        For Each obj_Cell In Selection.Cells
            With obj_Cell
                sumaTotalFrames = sumaTotalFrames + f_CalculateTcInFrames(.Text, framesRef)
            End With
         Next
    f_CalculateRangeTC = f_ConvertFramesTo_HHMMSSFF(sumaTotalFrames, framesRef)
End Function
```

Public Function f_CalculateTcInFrames

```
Public Function f_CalculateTcInFrames(ByVal numToConvert As String, ByVal framesRef As Double) As Double
    Dim fra2f, seg2f, min2f, hor2f As Double
    fra2f = 0
    seg2f = 0
    min2f = 0
    hor2f = 0
    ‘This two sentences convert an unformated number to correct format  1:23:05  to  00012305
    ‘But this not work with this:   1:1:02 (1 minute, 1 second, 2 frames)  becomes 00001102  ¡ERROR!
    numToConvert = Replace(numToConvert, ":", "")
    numToConvert =  Right("00000000" & numToConvert, 8)

    fra2f = Mid(numToConvert, 7, 2)                                 'Frames to frames
    seg2f = Mid(numToConvert, 5, 2) * (framesRef)               ‘Seconds to frames
    min2f = Mid(numToConvert, 3, 2) * (60 * framesRef)      ‘Minutes to frames
    hor2f = Mid(numToConvert, 1, 2) * (3600 * framesRef)        ‘Hours to frames
    sumaFrames = hor2f + min2f + seg2f + fra2f
     f_CalculateTcInFrames = sumaFrames        'Salimos de la función y devolvemos el valor.
Exit Function
```